# Trying to use selenium for a scrape automation, but the website can detect selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to use code to scrape some court records and gather data as an experiment. This will have been my fourth selenium automation, and my first time running into this.

the website: https://www.dallascounty.org/criminalBackgroundSearch/searchByCase

edit: the website says it is down, but it is not. if you search "jones" in the last name, you'll get some cases returned.

What's being done is, once the website is open (1) click case number form, (2) feed a case number in it, then (3) click "search by case number."

code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(link)
driver.get('https://www.dallascounty.org/criminalBackgroundSearch/searchByCase')

case_number= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form[2]/div[3]/div/input")
case_number.send_keys(case_numbers[0])

button=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form[2]/div[4]/div/input")
button.click()
```

As soon as I click the button, I'm reverted back to the original search screen. I've tried time.sleep() and my IP isn't blacklisted, but I've found that as soon as I open the link in driver.get(), even if i manually type in a case number, I'm reverted to the same search screen. This leads me to thinking that it's able to detect the program upon opening it.

Are there any solutions for this case? I see recaptcha in the javascript. There's no captcha challenge or anything, though.

Comment: The website you linked states the service is unavailable. `This service is temporarily unavailable, please try again later`

Comment: it's not, though. if you search "jones" in the last name, you'll get some results.

Comment: There is an issue in the service of the site and why are you using absolute XPath don't use it please use relative XPath

Comment: it's not a problem with the site. if you go to [https://www.dallascounty.org/criminalBackgroundSearch] and click continue, "captcha" is appended to the link. the problem seems to be invisible recaptchas.

Answer (score 0):

Their website is protected by recaptcha, it's super hard to beat Google's captcha systems, honestly I wouldn't bother trying. Finding a hack that works is like winning the lottery and it'll probably only work temporarily if the site uses an updated version.